# How can this page scroll (it doesn't work properly)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I tried many different options, none works. The most close to what I want is this following code.

```
<div>
    <header class="w3-container w3-blue">
        <h1>My website</h1>
    </header>
    <input id="surname_input" type="text" class="w3-input" placeholder="Name (required)">
    <br/>
    <div class="w3-container" style="position: absolute; bottom: 43px; top: 117.4px; left: 0px; right: 0px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <ul id="messages" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; z-index: -1;">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
<form id="chat_form" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%">
    <textarea   id="chat_input"
                class="w3-input"
                autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Enter text here..."
                onkeyup="auto_grow(this)"
                style="border-top: 1px solid #808080; height: 43px; overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>
```

I can get the scroll working if I change the position from absolute to relative of the `<ul>` but then it just does not work as expected (the messages spawning just on the top of the input).
I though I made it work but apparently there are issues every way...
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It's obvious, the messages should be spawned just next to the input going up after each sent messages, and si we can scrolls y to review the older ones

Comment: JS is just to append messages (li)

Answer (score 0):

here is the link below ... i think it will help you to create this kind of work:
[Sample code of chat application](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931)